# What is the Purpose of "postmessage" in a Redirect URI?

Tags: authentication, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-authentication

To my knowledge, in Google's authentication code flow it is required for the redirect_uri to be 'postmessage' instead of a URI.

**Could anyone explain what this value is specifically doing?**

My best explanation is that it tells the browser to return to where the post came from, but I have no documentation to back this assumption up.

There seems to be zero documentation on this topic, yet it is the given solution in most scenarios.
Any clarification would be nice.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a bit of (old) documentation here:
https://developers.google.com/+/sign-in-faq
that shows this is a Google+ Signin specific parameter to be used with Javascript apps:

> REDIRECT_URI  If a URL is present you are using the web redirect
>   approach. To take full advantage of Google+ Sign-In features, consider
>   using the JS widget approach. With the JS approach, the value of
>   redirect_uri should be postmessage.

Basically the `redirect_uri` value does not get used by the JS widget so it functions as an empty value.

Answer (score 0):

When using a popup for an Oauth flow, the popup will send the result back to the main window using

`window.parent.postMessage(message, 'accepted urls')`

So there is no "redirect url" used, and the result is redirected by using the javascript "postmessage" function.

I feel like it's a bug in Google's code that they want you to submit this as the redirect url for verification!