# Google Identity for server-side web app - redirect URI mismatch

Tags: google-api, nestjs, google-identity

I'm attempting to set up the [Code Model](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/use-code-model) for Google authentication, so that my user can oauth with Google and my app can retrieve their Calendar data. I'm stuck on [step 5 here](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/web-server#exchange-authorization-code), where I'm supposed to exchange the authorization code for refresh and access tokens. I'm using nestjs in the backend and React in the frontend.

What I've done already that's working:

1. User clicks a button on my web app's page
2. Client sets up `google.accounts.oauth2.initCodeClient` with the `/calendar` scope, in `ux_mode: popup`
3. User is shown the Google popup and can auth thru that
4. Client receives a response from Google containing the authorization code
5. Client makes a POST call to my backend to send it just that authorization code

In step 5, the client makes the POST call to localhost:4000/auth/google-test. In the backend, I'm using the `googleapis` package and have:

```
export const oauth2Client = new google.auth.OAuth2(
  process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID,
  process.env.GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET,
  'http://localhost:4000/'  // <- note, I'm not sure if this is corect
);
```

And in the relevant controller route, I'm doing:

```
    @Post('google-test')
    public async googleTest(@Body() bodyReceived: any): Promise<any> {
        let { code } = bodyReceived
        let { tokens } = await oauth2Client.getToken(code)
        oauth2Client.setCredentials(tokens);
        console.log('Tokens: ' + tokens);
        return
```

The error I'm getting is related to `oauth2Client.getToken(code)`, and the error is a `redirect_uri_mismatch`. In GCP for the credentials for this app, I've added all of these as "Authorized redirect URIs":

- http://localhost:3000/home
- http://localhost:4000/auth/google-test
- http://localhost:4000

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: if you check the error message it will tell exactly what the redirect uri is missing in google cloud console.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QHz1Rs6lZHQ

Comment: The error message is coming to my server, so I can't get to the same kind of error page in the video. When I look more closely at the error I get on the server, it's a longer JSON with the request I tried to send, but no message about what redirect_uri is missing

Comment: well the consent screen needs to be shown to the user how do you plan to do this on a server?

Comment: Figured out how to get around this - see my answer below (credit to another SO post). To answer your question, what I have working is the client initiating the oauth flow, then passing along the authorization code to the server, which then exchanges that for an access token which gets passed back to the client. It's what Google calls the "code model" of oauth.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a bit more Googling, but turns out that the right answer is to have my server make the token call with the redirect uri as `"postmessage"`.

[This SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51106569/what-is-the-purpose-of-postmessage-in-a-redirect-uri) gives a bit more context. A somewhat unbelievable message, but it seems to work for my app.

Comment: Thanks for this - a little more info in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48121098/1006183) also.

Answer (score 0):

It is evidently that what is happening is that the redirect URI does not match with the one in the GCP. This usually happens because backend tools such as Nestjs may be appending a trailing '/' to the URL and it may be interpreted as being part of the redirect_uri value.

You can try by temoving any trailing '/' via this following method `oauthurl.replace(/\/$/, '')`

Moreover, you can pass the generated auth URL to a meta tag. And check the html header to confirm what is the URL value.